# Firebase Functions: Random 404's

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase functions on a server for API calls. Everything works fine 70% of the time, but all of a sudden some of my function calls start failing to execute, giving my API a 404, and don't work for the next few hours.

In my StackDriver I can see the function isn't called again when I try. My API just gives me a 404 without ever reaching the server.

Below is one of the calls that fails once in a while. Going to the URL i'm fetching, the GET result always shows up, so I have no clue what the issue is.

API call:

```
const getCreators = () => {
  return window
    .fetch(url + '/get-creators', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status === 200) {
        return res.json();
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data || data.error) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return data;
      }
    });
};
```

Server code:

```
const app = express();

  app.get('/get-creators', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('creators: ');
    creators
      .find()
      .toArray()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).send(result);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('error');
        res.send('error');
      });
  });

app.listen(4242, () => console.log(`Node server listening at https ${4242}!`));

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: If the request doesn't reach the server how come the response is a 404? Normally you get a network error if a network request doesn't reach the server. If you get a response (even if it is an error response) you've reached the server.

Comment: @3limin4t0r That's what I thought, it doesn't make any sense. It may be trying to search locally, but logging my result in api it has the correct url as being attempted to reach.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Found the answer. Server was listening locally everyone once in a while, and not telling me. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Found it. You don't want the below code on your server:

```
app.listen(4242, () => console.log(`Node server listening at https ${4242}!`));
```

I commented this code out, republished, and all is well.

I thought having this didn't make a difference, but apparently once in a blue moon it can and will try to make the server listen locally, which gave me a 404.

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution, but this answer doesn't really explain a lot. What's up with the code block? Did you add that code? Remove it? Change it? Adding a before and after would help explaining for future readers. Normally you can see what changed by looking at the code in the question first, but this line is nowhere to be found.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I agree, updating it now to make it more clear. Thanks!